# What is usually preferred in a sub-proc, INZ during variable declaration or using CLEAR?

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle, rpg

Assuming both choices will yield same results, what choice do you usually make and why?

```
dcl-proc test_proc ;
   ...
   dcl-s count  int(5) inz ;
   ...
   // use count
end-proc ;
```

or

```
dcl-proc test_proc ;
   ...
   dcl-s count  int(5) ;
   ...
   clear count
   // use count
end-proc ;
```

Also, As the scope of variable *count* is local, do we even need to use either of them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need INZ to be able to use RESET.

But it's best to use RESET only when the RESET value would be different from the CLEAR value.

Using RESET requires the compiler to generate extra storage and extra instructions to save the initial value.

Comment: If I need that functionality, either the compiler will generate the storage for the RESET, or I will have to explicitly do so. Or worse: type the initialiser Magic Number multiple times throughout the code block.  I prefer RESET because it's pretty clear (hee hee) that something unusual is happening at this point in the code.

Answer (score 5):

RPG stand-a-lone variables are initialized to their defaults.  For all numeric fields the default is 0.

Thus, for your local (and non-static) variable you don't need `INZ` nor use `CLEAR` or `RESET` prior to use.

`RESET` will always reset the variable to it's initialized value.
`CLEAR` will reset the variable to the type default value.

Examples:
`dcl-s myNum int(5);`

- `CLEAR myNum;` --> `myNum` == 0
- `RESET myNum;` --> `myNum` == 0

`dcl-s myNum int(5) inz(5);`

- `CLEAR myNum;` --> `myNum` == 0
- `RESET myNum;` --> `myNum` == 5

**Addendum**
The only thing I routinely use INZ on are data structures.  Without INZ, the DS is initialized to blanks; regardless of the data types of the subfields.  With INZ, each subfield is initialized to it's type default.

Answer (score 3):

I use INZ on every declaration.

Imagine adding a DS to a sub-proc that has no INZ keywords. I might not remember to INZ the DS, even though that's invariably necessary to get the 'natural' behaviour of the subfields.

I use CLEAR or RESET specifically to signal intent that something needing my focus is happening in the code - most often reusing a variable.

Comment: This is my favored technique, though I don't think I have ever used RESET. and instead of CLEAR, I just assign the natural value explicitly `ix = 0` or `str = ''`.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, I prefer the first option. Just out of habit, always initialize variables.
If we are talking about global or static variables, then if necessary I use clear or reset. they can contain the value left from the last call in this activation group.

Comment: I think that's a good habit to always initialize. The RPG compiler initializes standalone fields, but compilers for other languages might not. Just be careful about initializing varying-length fields (VARCHAR etc). If you initialize to INZ(*BLANKS), the length will get set to the maximum length. That might be ok, but it might not be what you want. If you just put INZ, it will get initialized to a length of zero. You could also code INZ('') to get it initialized with a length of zero if you want to put an explicit INZ value.

Comment: @BarbaraMorris You're right. I have been writing in C/C++ for many years (approximately from 1990 to 2017 only in C/C++, now more in RPG but sometimes in C/C++ too). Hence the habit - "an uninitialized variable is bad and fraught with unpredictable behavior."
And again you are absolutely right about varchar initialization - initializing it *blanks is wrong. But to completely uninitialize is even more wrong. faced with the fact that in a varchar variable without inz in the length field there may be a value that exceeds the size of this variable.

Comment: Victor, you're right that for a varchar subfield it's important to initialize it since the default initialization of x'4040' or x'40404040'  is either wrong or invalid. But that's only for subfields. If you don't initialize a varchar standalone field explicitly, it gets initialized implicitly with a length of 0.

Comment: Victor, that's not true that var would contain '9876556789' after the second assignment. The EVAL opcode completely updates the field, so with or without the clear, var would contain '98765' followed by 5 blanks. Maybe you were thinking of the MOVE or MOVEL opcode which don't pad with blanks unless you code the P extender, MOVE(P) or MOVEL(P).

Comment: @BarbaraMorris I don’t remember the situation now, but I came across the fact that when a char is assigned a string with a length less than its size, it is not cleared beforehand. And it certainly was in FullFree RPGLE.
Although, perhaps, this concerned the fields of structures.
One way or another, for reliability, I clean it in such situations.

Comment: The correctness of the length field for varchar is easily checked by the following method:

dcl-s vChar   varchar(100);
dcl-s vchLen uns(5) based(pVChar);

pVChar = %addr(vChar);

After that, vchLen contains the value of the length field of the varchar variable. You can check and if it is not correct, set the correct value.

Comment: @VictorPomortseff - I am sure you experienced *something* that made such a strong impression on you that you now take extra care to clear a string before reassigning it, even in "fully free" code (in which case it would have had to be something other than MOVE or MOVEL). But the example in your answer is *factually incorrect*, as Barbara pointed out. So I have to consider this a bad answer until you edit it to show an example that correctly illustrates your point.

Comment: @JohnY, I admit that I was wrong and I apologize for the false information.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my views...

- Pros of using INZ: can RESET it to 0 - as required going forward (i.e. better maintainability)
- Cons of using CLEAR: one extra instruction

Comment: Counting instructions is an ineffective way to evaluate maintainability. That's an opinion, but this is a style question...